# How to resolve a client_id rejected error

Tags: support

So I am digging into the API and trying to learn it by creating my own application. I have registered for a key and currently hosting the application locally (http://localhost). On login, I receive an error stating that the client_id was rejected.

How does one resolve this error? Or are the underlying combination of reasons to broad? I have inspected the documentation and did not find any notes on this error.

<sub>(The client_id is the number for your application right? http://stackapps.com/apps/edit/[client_id])</sub>

Comment: You do have an API v2.0 key, right? (It will show up [here](http://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/).)

Comment: Hmm, I thought so I did use http://stackapps.com/apps/register but the app does not show up there only under http://stackapps.com/apps/. So registering at http://stackapps.com/apps/register does not give you the API v2.0 key? I'm in the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27/stack-apps) :) @GeorgeEdison